# XMLFormatter issue with combimation of LF and CR LF

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, xml-formatting

I am doing XML Format using dom4j Outpurformat and Document objects.

I am setting lineseparator based on OS if `Win -> \r\n and Linux -> \n`

If I pass single line xml file it working fine getting expected EOL (`CR LF`).

But If I pass multiple line xml file whatever the existing line comes with (`LF`)  new lines are comes with (`CR LF`)

ex :
Input file :

```
    <root>
      <emp>
        <name>myname</name>
      </emp>
    </root>
```

output :

```
    <root> LF
    CR LF
      <emp>LF
    CR LF
        <name>myname</name>LF
    CR LF
      </emp>LF
    CR LF
    </root>LF
    CR LF
```

I have tried to replace the EOL still not working 
I tried both way

```
xmlContent= xmlContent.replaceAll("\n","\r\n")
xmlContent = xmlContent.replaceAll("\\n","\r\n")
```

Its working fine in linux as expected all time "LF", but the above mentioned problem is on windows host. its coming with combination of LF and CF LF.

Comment: Is the output  coming from a Windows host ?

Comment: yes windows host

Answer (score 0):

String are immutable in java. So have to replace line breaks and assign to variable.

- CR = \r; - Carriage Return
- LF = \n; - Line Feed
- CRLF = \r\n - End of Line

  xmlContent = xmlContent.replaceAll("\r\n","").repalceAll("\n","").repalceAll("\r","");;

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the behavior of dom4j is correct. It just add newline (CR+LF for a windows os) while indenting output. The extra LF are coming from the original file (which i guess use the unix convention).
The xml parser interprets the LF in inputs as text nodes so you get them on the output too.
What if you try

```
xmlContent = xmlContent.replaceAll("\x0a","")
```

Otherwise you could configure your xml reader to ignore whitespace

```
SAXReader xmlReader = new SAXReader();
xmlReader.setStripWhitespaceText(true);
```

but this will affect the white spaces inside elements too.

Comment: this is not related to whitespace, as I mentioned all lines from input files are modified with EOL as LF (Linux format), even I convert EOL for windows using notepad++. using formatter whatever new line are added it comes with "CR LF".

Comment: which version of Dom4j are you using ?

Comment: using dom4j 1.6.1